# PHP form not processing in process.php

Tags: php, forms, processing

I'm having difficulty figuring out why my PHP form is processing on process.php but not returning to the form page with the appropriate $messages. Am I missing a line of code? I wrote this all up myself and it's the first time.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Contact Form - jQuery</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>    
    <h3>Contact Us</h3>
    <?php echo $contact_message; ?>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action="process.php">
        <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST[name]; ?>" placeholder="Name" required/>
        <br>
        <input name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $_POST[email]; ?>" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" required/>
        <br>
        <textarea name="message" class="message" placeholder="We can answer your questions." required>
            <?php echo $_POST[message]; ?>
        </textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn send">
            <img src="img/send.png">
        </button>
        <br>
        <?php echo $contact_success_message; ?>
    </form>
    <!--close contact form-->    
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my `process.php`

```
<?php

//checks for valid email
function is_valid_email($email) {
    $result = true;
    $pattern = '/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i';
    if(!preg_match($pattern, $email)) {
        $result = false;
    }
    return $result;
}

//when send is pressed, validate fields
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $valid = true;
    $contact_message = '';
    if ( $_POST['name'] == "" ) {
        $contact_message .= "You forgot to tell us your name. ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( !is_valid_email($_POST['email']) ) {
        $contact_message .= "A valid email is required, don't worry we don't share it with anyone. "; 
        $valid = false; 
    }
    if ( $_POST['message'] == "" ) {
        $contact_message .= "What did you want to ask us? ";
        $valid = false; 
    }
    //if everything checks out, send the message! 
    if ( $valid == true ) {
        $safe_email = str_replace("\r\n","",$_POST[email]);
        $mail = "From: $_POST[name]\n";
        $mail .= "Email: $_POST[email]\n";
        $mail .= "$_POST[message]\n";
        mail('ME@MYEMAIL.COM','New Contact from RN+',$mail,"From: $safe_email\r\n");
        $contact_success_message = 'Brilliant I say! We will be in contact with you shortly.';
        //clear form when submission is successful
        unset($_POST);
    }
}
?>
```

I could have sworn that I've used this before but this time it's not returning to the contact page.

Comment: process.php has no code that does any redirection.  If the form is not valid, it appears to just display a blank page.  If the form is valid, it appears to send the mail and then show a blank page as well.  Perhaps you `include`ed that script in your previous contact form rather than posting to it directly?

Comment: try comment out  unset($_POST); it unsetting the post values in the reload

Comment: @drew010 So, at the top of my contact page add an 
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
include('process.php')
}

Comment: @user1179459 I commented it out and it didn't change anything. Sorry I wasn't specific, it's coming to a blank page and is stuck at process.php instead of returning to the contact page with a success or error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you meant to use the code like this:

form.php

```
<?php include 'process.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Contact Form - jQuery</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h3>Contact Us</h3>
            <?php echo $contact_message; ?>
            <form id="myForm" method="post" action="process.php">
                <input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $_POST[name]; ?>" placeholder="Name" required/><br>
                <input name="email" type="email" value="<?php echo $_POST[email]; ?>" placeholder="you@yourmail.com" required/><br>
                <textarea name="message" class="message" placeholder="We can answer your questions." required><?php echo $_POST[message]; ?></textarea><br>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn send"><img src="img/se
__
formnd.png"></button><br>
                <?php echo $contact_success_message; ?>
            </form><!--close contact form-->

</body>
</html>
```

The form processor will set the appropriate variables you are outputting in your HTML code.  Since process.php checks if the method is POST, you don't have to do that in the form page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want process.php to redirect back to your form, you need to add a PHP header code like: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/form.php');`

If you want to carry through any data back to the original page, include it in the URL as a GET variable: `header('Location: http://www.example.com/form.php?message='.$messagetext);` You can then retrieve this on your form page through use of GET: `echo $contact_success_message = $_GET['message'];`

Do not forget to `exit(); or die();` after your redirect!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any reason for excluding a single PHP page, you could merge the two (form and process) into one php page.

```
<?php
//checks for valid email function
...
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
...
}
?>
...your HTML goes here...
```

This will display just the form if no data has been submitted, and if the form has been submitted will "reload" the page, perform the action, and display the appropriate message. Change the form action to `action=""` so the file will post to itself.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using jQuery validation.  It is easier and will help with any issues you might have in returning the message.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Something like this...

```
$("#myForm").validate({
rules: {
    name: { required: true; }
},
messages: {
name: "You forgot to tell us your name.",
}
```

});

You can do this for email fields and for your whole form.  You can find plenty of examples online.

Just include your other fields.  If you do it this way the validation is client side and the form will process and then you forward to a thank you for contacting us page.